# The reverse state monad in Coq

Tags: haskell, monads, lazy-evaluation, coq, state-monad

In Haskell, the following definition of bind is accepted:

```
type RState s a = s -> (a, s)

bind :: RState s a -> (a -> RState s b) -> RState s b 
bind sf f = \s ->
  let (a, s'') = sf s'
      (b, s') = f a s
  in (b, s'')
```

How can I get a similar definition accepted by Coq?
My attempt is:

```
Definition RState (S A : Type) : Type := S -> A * S.

Definition bind (S A B : Type) (sf : RState S A) (f : A -> RState S B) : RState S B :=
  fun s =>
    let (a, s'') := sf s' in
    let (b, s') := f a s in
    (b, s'').
```

But it fails with the following error message:

```
Error: The reference s' was not found in the current environment.
```

Comment: The trick works in Haskell because the two bindings in the `let` expression are mutually recursive. IDK how it works in Coq but I'm guessing there's some sort of `mutual` keyword?

Comment: You will also need to prove termination using a well-founded relation. I'm not sure if that is possible here without also taking some kind of additional (proof?) argument in `bind` (maybe the particular well-founded relation to use).

Answer (score 0):

Assume `g :: s -> s`. Consider

```
sf :: RState s s
sf = get = \s -> (s, s)

f :: s -> RState s s
f = put . g = \a _ -> ((), g a)
```

We get:

```
bind sf f = \s ->
  let (a, s'') = sf s'
      (b, s') = f a s
  in (b, s'')
          = \s ->
  let (a, s'') = (s', s')
      (b, s') = ((), g a)
  in (b, s'')
          = \s ->
  let (b, s') = ((), g s')
  in (b, s')
          = \s ->
  let s' = g s' in ((), s')
```

This involves computing a fixed point for `g`, which is in general impossible in Coq due to the possible lack of termination.

As David Young mentions above, if something like `bind` is doable in Coq, it must be enhanced with proof terms proving that this recursion terminates. This enhancement is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

`bind` needs a proof that the functions will actually return.  If you add an argument `H` with a type to this effect that depends on the actual `sf`, `f`, and `s` values, you can then extract the desired `(b, s'')` pair from that "certified" term `H`.

Note that *how to actually compute* the `sf` and `f` functions has to be explained in the construction of `H`, for the particular `sf`, `f`, and `s`.

(There might be other/better ways of achieveing this. Hopefully someone else can add to this thread.)

```
Definition RState (S A : Type) : Type := S -> A * S.

Section Bind.
  Variables S A B:Type.

  (* define a type that a proof should have *)
  Definition sf_f_s_are_ok (sf : RState S A) (f : A -> RState S B) (s:S) :=
    {x | exists a s'' b s', x = (a, s'', b, s') /\
         (a, s'') = sf s' /\ (b, s') = f a s}.

  (* bind just returns the values we were interested in *)
  Definition bind sf f (s:S) (H : sf_f_s_are_ok sf f s) :=
    match H with exist _ (a, s'', b, s') _ => (b, s'') end.

  (* make sure bind is ok *)
  Lemma bind_is_ok: forall sf f s H b s'',
      bind sf f s H = (b, s'') -> exists a s', (a,s'') = sf s' /\ (b,s') = f a s.
  Proof.
    intros sf f s [[[[a s''0] b0] s'] [a0 [b1 [s'0 [s''1 [Ha [Hb Hc]]]]]]] b s'' H0.
    simpl in H0; generalize H0 Ha Hb Hc; do 4 inversion 1; subst; eauto.
  Qed.
End Bind.
```